# Split an expression in RDLC report

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, rdlc

Tool: Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

I have an RDLC textbox expression where I want to split it based on ',' separated values and display those values in new line. For Example,

Value : `Abc, Xyz, STU`

The above value need to be displayed as :

```
Abc
Xyz
STU
```

I have tried the below expression:

```
  IIf((Split(Parameters!rpField.Value,",").Length = 2), 
        Split(Parameters!rpField.Value, ",").GetValue(0) +System.Environment.NewLine+ Split(Parameters!rpField.Value,",").GetValue(1), "")
```

The result is `#Error`.

How can I accomplish this in SSRS?

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing the commas with a NewLine? What you show seems like overkill.

Comment: @R.Richards That will work provided you want new lines inside the same textbox - not if you want new rows in a tablix.

Comment: So, you want to split a comma separated list and use it for the data source, or details, of a Tablix?

Comment: I want it to be displayed in the same textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same structure you proposed, this worked for me:

```
=Split(CStr(Parameters!rpField.Value), ",").GetValue(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to replace the commas with new lines, if you want them all in the same textbox?

If that is the case, you can simply use `replace`:

```
=replace("Abc, Xyz, STU", ", ", vbcrlf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have done it using Instr function and replaced ',' with NewLine as below:

```
   =IIF(Parameters!rpField.Value <> "" ,iif(Instr(Parameters!Field.Value, ",") > 0 ,
     " "+Replace(Parameters!rpField.Value,",",System.Environment.NewLine) +System.Environment.NewLine,
     " "+Parameters!Field.Value+ System.Environment.NewLine) ,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=JOIN(Split(Parameters!rpField.Value,","), System.Environment.NewLine)
```